# Apache .htaccess trick to authenticate only once for all subdomains?

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, .htaccess, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache .htaccess trick to authenticate only once for all subdomains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62868/apache-htaccess-trick-to-authenticate-only-once-for-all-subdomains)

I'm using something like this in .htaccess file to restrict access to the website:

```
AuthUserFile /some/directory/.passwd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

This works fine but the user is asked to authenticate each time a subdomain is changed, like user1.mywebsite.com, user2.mywebsite.com or just mywebsite.com

Is there a way to tell Apache2 that when a user is authenticated against one subdomain, it should grant him access to all others as well?