# Apache digest auth with custom login box

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a site with five subdomains:

sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.com
sub3.domain.com
sub4.domain.com
sub5.domain.com

When accessing on of these subdomains you get an login box similar to the solution in this question, 
[Apache .htaccess trick to authenticate only once for all subdomains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62843/apache-htaccess-trick-to-authenticate-only-once-for-all-subdomains)

Each subdomain is pointing to an internal site using mod_proxy.

My question is if it would be possible to swap the ugly default popup auth box against an html-page that i write?

Comment: Perhaps this can be done through some other system that can be put in front of the apache server, squid?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this (custom authentication page), you need to implement the authentication and authorization in the server-side pages, rather than having the webserver do it for you.

The 'default popup auth box' appears because Apache told the browser "I need a username and password". It can't ask for anything much more complicated than that.

You would need to remove the web server authentication and implement a custom login page and have each of the subdomains check to see if the user is correctly logged in (signed cookie or shared storage).

Note that this is a lot more work to implement than a simple 'ugly' browser popup.